# Анимация проигрывается только один раз

Tags: jquery, анимация, css-animation

Нужно, чтобы по клику на одну из двух кнопок проигрывалась анимация CSS. Для этого используется обработчик событий jQuery и функции *addClass()* и *removeClass()* со значением класса анимации. Но анимация проигрывается только один раз, по первому клику. Как сделать её постоянное повторение?

```js
var colors = ['black', 'red', 'green'];
var counter = 0;

$('#prev').click(function() {
  changeBackground(-1);
});
$('#next').click(function() {
  changeBackground(1);
});

function changeBackground(num) {

  counter += num;
  if (counter >= colors.length) counter = 0;
  if (counter < 0) counter = colors.length - 1;
  $('.background').css('background-color', colors[counter]);

  $('.background').removeClass('fade');
  $('.background').addClass('fade');
}
```

```css
.background {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#prev,
#next {
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
}

#prev {
  float: left;
}

#next {
  float: right;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="background">
  <button id="prev">Prev</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код js:

```
    var colors = ['black', 'red', 'green'], counter = 0;

    $('#prev').click(function() {
      changeBackground(-1);
    });
    $('#next').click(function() {
      changeBackground(1);
    });

    function changeBackground(num) {
      counter += num;
      if (counter >= colors.length) counter = 0;
      if (counter < 0) counter = colors.length - 1;

      var elem = $('.background');
      elem.css('background-color', colors[counter]);

      if (elem.css('animationName') === "fade")
        elem.css('animationName', 'fade2');
      else
        elem.css('animationName', 'fade');
    }
```

Код css:

```
    .fade {
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }

    @keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }

    @keyframes fade2 {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
```